# WCF Service- Sending back object to calling App

Tags: wcf

My WCF service(hosted as Windows Service), has some 'SendEmail' methods, which sends out emails after doing some processing.

Now, I have got another requirement where client wants to preview emails before they are being sent out, so my WCF service needs to return whole email object to calling web app.
If client is happy with emails object, they can simply click 'Send out' which will then again call WCF service to send the emails.

Because at times it can take a bit longer for emails object processingy, I do not want calling application to wait until emails object is ready.

Can anyone please guide what changes I need to make to my WCF service (which currently has all one way operation)?

Also, please guide me whether I need to go for Asynch operation or message queuing or may be a duplex contract?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description I think you will have to:

- Change current operation from sending email to storing email (probably in database).
- Add additional operation for retrieving prepared emails for current user
- Add additional method to confirm sending one or more emails and removing them from storage.

The process will be:

1. User will trigger some http request which will result in calling your WCF service for processing (first operation)
2. WCF service will initiate some processing (asynchronously or firt operation will be one-way so that client doesn't have to wait).
3. Processing will save email somehow
4. Depend on duration of processing you can either use AJAX to poll WebApp which will in turn poll WCF service for prepared emails or you will create separate page which will user have to access to see prepared emails. Both methods are using second operation.
5. User will check prepared email(s) and trigger http request which will result in calling third operation to send those emails.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav, yeah, this is how it should work. One query, If I go for the queuing/saving request to database part, how can I start an asynchronous method so that reporting service takes first request from the queue to process, should I start a new thread for that?

Comment: Does it mean that you want only single request to be processed at any given time?

Comment: yeah, think so. because once request is saved to database or queued, client can happily continue with other stuff... so service should take first unprocessed job from queue and start processing that. What should I do so my service picks job from the queue and start processing that? Also, btw is it possible to take more than one job from the queue for processing?

Comment: It is just up to you. Your windows service can have background thread which will periodically check the queue and take as many requests for processing as you want.

Comment: hmm, will you be able to guide me on how can I add background thread to current wcf service to take one or more request from the db queue. Or what do you think about adding another wcf service to do background tasks as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106369/wcf-polling-background-processing-and-resource-starvation

Comment: The thread is not in "Wcf service" but in Windows service hosting your Wcf service. Anyway if you are currently using one-way call you can let your service operation process the request but in such case if multiple clients call the service in the same time you will have multiple processed requests.

Comment: okay! well my question remain same :-( how should I make my wcf service start processing jobs from the queue when there is no request from client app for same? Sorry for my misunderstanding.

Comment: There are two approaches: 1. You will let your wcf service process the request. So when the client calls request it will not only store info but it will also process request because by default each wcf service call is processed in separate thread. 2. Your wcf service will only put request to queue and another thread running in your hosting windows service will grab that request and start processing.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options:

- Use Ladislav's approach. Only to add that service returns a token and then client uses the token to poll until a time out or a successful response. Also server keeps these temp emails for a while and after a timeout purges them.
- Use duplex communication so that server also gets a way to callback the client and does so when it has finished processing. **But don't do this** - and here is [my view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265033/mysterious-problem-in-wcf-and-iis/4265457#4265457) why not.
- Use an Asynchronous approach. You can find nice info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734701.aspx).

Comment: Don't use Duplex from ASP.NET application, it will not work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157091/problem-with-using-wcf-callback-and-asp-net-to-implement-publish-subscribe-patter/5157324#5157324